# multiuser desktop sharing between windows and ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I was trying to use a software installed on windows using remote desktop client remmina in ubuntu, is this possible that i can use that software from ubuntu and other user can also use that software on that windows(on which software is installed) simultaneously without affecting each others functionality?

Comment: I'm confused. Which software is supposed to run on what system? What do you mean by “simultaneously“? What “functionality“ do you fear may be affected?